# Azure Management URL

Tags: azure

So, finally I decided to jump into the Azure bandwagon and create my own portal. At the moment, my apps are hosted on Google Apps and I'm considering moving them to Azure and O365 before which I wanted to trial and get the taste of MS Azure.

I signed up for a trial subscription and my management URL ended up something like https://manage.windowsazure.com/@MynameMydomainname.onmicrosoft.com. So I decided to delete this account and set up a new account altogether trying to sign up with a new domain alias. And now it is https://manage.windowsazure.com/@MyaliasMydomainname.onmicrosoft.com. MS Support would't help and would want me to sign up for O365 which I don't want to at the moment.

Why my management portal always has my complete e-mail address and how do I edit it?

Edit: Thought would add the following example to explain my problem a bit easier.

My name is Muthu and I already have an e-mail address Muthu@Contoso.com and now I attempt to set-up my Azure around it. I sign up for a Microsoft account with the e-mail address Muthu@Contoso.com, provide my card details and successfully set up the account. Now, the logon URL looks like https://manage.windowsazure.com/@MuthuContoso.onmicrosoft.com and the default directory has the UPN of @muthucontoso.onmicrosoft.com.

I set up an account for a user Eddie, George and Mark and their UPN appears as follows:

```
Eddie@muthucontoso.onmicrosoft.com
George@muthucontoso.onmicrosoft.com and
Mark@muthucontoso.onmicrosoft.com.
```

How do I get rid of my name from the domain name here?

P.S.: I managed to get rid of my name from the Management portal URL by simply verifying my ownership of contoso.com using O365 control panel but still couldn't get around to rename the default directory. I can't force my name for the users in my organization just because I signed up for it. There should be some way around. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

When loging in you're actually signing in to an aad tenant.. Which is bound to a subscription... As you can have multiple subscriptions and tenants they need to show you where you are

Comment: So, can I add another subscription to the same e-mail address as a Service Administrator?

Comment: yes, as long you hook up a credit card to it :-) the only thing that you can't do is have multiple passes on the same email

Comment: yes , except for passes, that you can only go on 1 mail address only. but you can be service admin on multiple subscriptions and or co-admin

Comment: I just editied the original post to reflect my question with more accuracy. Thanks for your attempts to help.